# How can I take a long list of numbers, which are listed among each other in the Python Console and put it in one long variable?

Tags: python, string, io, console, int

I want to read a long list of numbers in the one program like so: [(picture of console output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqYSv.png)
and give those numbers as an input to an other program and make a long variable, containing all of those numbers in a String.

I had something like this in mind:
    ("1234 124234423223 42342 2423 43235433453453 34534 22345 678867 456464 234234")

Sorry if this question is not perfectly asked I'm kinda new here, but if there should be questions please let me know, I will try to respond immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just join them with a space as a delimeter.

```
numbers = ['123', '456', '789']
print(' '.join(numbers))
```

Output:

`123 456 789`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in traditional way.

```
numList = ['111093093213091231', '4111156', '9','209302383280']

st = ""
for num in numList:
    st = st+" "+num
print(st)
```

Other way using join has already been answered well.

Answer (score 0):

So in unix based OSs you can use the pipe operator (`|`)

Something like this

Terminal:

```
python job1.py | python job2.py
```

job1.py:

```
for element in some_list:
    print(element)
```

job2.py:

```
result = [int(line.strip()) for line sys.stdin.readlines()]
result = ' '.join(result)
```